# RSelenium: Timeout error while trying to connect to server running on docker using remoteDriver$open()

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, ip, rselenium, connection-timeout

This problem seems to be relatively common but none of the fixes I have seen work for me.

I am using 64 bit Windows 10.

I am trying to use RSelenium using docker. I have been trying to roughly follow the documentation here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/docker.html

I have tried starting the docker container using both of the following:

```
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome

docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
```

I have been using inspect  on the resulting container to get the docker host IP. I found that it was 172.17.0.2.

In R I have tried running the following, using the host IP I found above.

```
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "172.17.0.2", port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
Sys.sleep(15)
remDr$open()
```

I get the following output:

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Timeout was reached: [172.17.0.2:4445] Connection timeout after 10012 ms
```

I have tried using "localhost" as the value for remoteServerAddr in remoteDriver(). Doing so does not give me a timeout but the remote driver does not seem to actually connect to anything:

```
> remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
> Sys.sleep(15)
> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$id
[1] NA
```

I read that using "localhost" does not work on Windows in general, so it might not be worth paying attention to this.

I also read somewhere that 172.17.0.2 is an internal address that is not open to the actual Windows computer and that I should use 192.168.99.100 instead. Using this second address gives me the same error:

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Timeout was reached: [192.168.99.100:4445] Connection timeout after 10009 ms
```

Most of the advice I have seen suggests fixing this error by correctly defining remoteServerAddr in remoteDriver() so I am not sure what else I can do. I would like to try increasing the timeout time but I have not figured out how to do so for remDr$open(). I am aware that you can change the timeout time for remote drivers, but this seems to only be for commands that are executed once a server has been connected to.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this yet?